# svg element not appearing in the body using d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am following a tutorial and I am trying to create an svg element using d3. however when I run it and inspect the page on chrome, the svg element isnt showing up in the body. I'm sure that the .html file is referencing the correct js file, but I cant figure out why the element isn't appending

this is my html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>example</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
            <script type="/text/javascript" src="d3.v3.min.js">
            </script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <script type="/text/javascript" src="shapes.js"></script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

and this is my js code

```
    var dataArray = [2,13,15];
    d3.select("body").append("svg");
```

Comment: have a look in the console if there are errors, add `console.log('debug');` to your js file to be sure it is run

Comment: i added that to my js file and there aren't any errors

Comment: but do you see the text from the `console.log`, look in the `sources` tab to see if your javascript file is loaded

Comment: when I look in sources I see that d3.html and style.css are in the directory but I don't see my shapes.js file

Comment: there is no output in the console either

Comment: The example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D3.js adds `witdh`and `height` to the new `svg` child. Your code seems to be missing these attributes. May be your svg's size is 0 by 0?

Comment: then the JS file is not executed, add a deliberate error to be sure, or set a break point

Answer (score 0):

It's your `type` attributes on your `script` tags:

```
/text/javascript
```

is not valid, it's:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="shapes.js"></script>
```

With no leading slash...